# Is there an elegant way to check if multiple variables equal one value or vice versa

Tags: c, syntax

Is there a neater/shorter way to write out things like:

`if(var1 == 1 && var2 == 1 && var3 == 1)`

or

`if(var1 == 1 || var1 == 4 || var1 == 6)`

I know there's all sorts of commonly used syntax shortcuts that make things look a bit cleaner and I figured there may be some other way to write it that I don't know of considering how bulky it gets.

Comment: The two cases are quite different. The second one could be implemented with a fall-through `switch/case`. With the first one it depends on how the vars are related. If they can be put into an array, you could do some `memcmp` tricks.

Comment: How about a not so elegant `(1u * var1 * var2 * var3) == 1`?  Much depends on the _type_ of the variables.

Comment: @KemVolt, do you want _elegance_, for `if(var1 == 1 && var2 == 1 && var3 == 1)` is elegant?  Do you want a "neater/shorter" and don't think your compiler to emit efficient code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there an elegant way

You can throw as many abstractions as you want, and it will just result in pilling up layers and more code to debug. Bottom line, the code you presented is completely fine, readable, clear, short and very elegant.

The only thing I would do is remove [magic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)) by declaring a variable with readable name. Like `int this_is_important_number = 1; if (var1 == this_is_important_number && var2 == this_is_important_number  && var3 == this_is_important_number)`.

You can throw a macro at it:

```
#define ALL_EQ_1(x, a)  ((x) == (a))
#define ALL_EQ_2(x, a, ...)  ALL_EQ_1(x, a) && ALL_EQ_1(x, __VA_ARGS__)
#define ALL_EQ_3(x, a, ...)  ALL_EQ_1(x, a) && ALL_EQ_2(x, __VA_ARGS__)
#define ALL_EQ_N(_4,_3,_2,_1,N,...)  \
        ALL_EQ##N
#define ALL_EQ(x, ...)  \
        (ALL_EQ_N(__VA_ARGS__,_4,_3,_2,_1)(x,__VA_ARGS__))
int main() {
    int var1 = 1, var2 = 2, var3 = 3;
    return ALL_EQ(1, var1, var2, var3);
}
```

You can throw a variadic function at it:

```
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <limits.h>
bool all_eq_INT_MAX_v(int to, va_list va) {
    while (1) {
        const int v = va_arg(va, int);
        if (v == INT_MAX) {
            break;
        }
        if (v != to) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
bool all_eq_INT_MAX(int to, ...) {
    va_list va;
    va_start(va, to);
    const bool r = all_eq_INT_MAX_v(to, va);
    va_end(va);
    return r;
}
#define all_eq(x, ...)  all_eq_INT_MAX(x, __VA_ARGS__, INT_MAX)

int main() {
    int var1 = 1, var2 = 1, var3 = 1;
    return all_eq(1, var1, var2, var3);
}
```

Or any other abstraction. The problem, is that you have to then later maintain and debug such code, which is not worth it. A simple `if` statement is just great.

Comment: In my opinion it is an awful unreadable code that makes a simple if statement  too complicated.

Answer (score 1):

For the *or* statement, you could use a switch statement where the results fall through the cases until you reach a desired state.

```c
switch(variable) {
    case 1:
    case 4:
    case 6:
        // do thing
    default:
        // handle any other cases
}
```

The *and* statement is limited. You could try what Eugene Sh. mentioned above with memcmp.

Comment: No - it is not an equivalent of the given if.

Comment: The switch fallthrough noted in the comments would have been `case 1: \n case 4: \n case 6:`, not individual switch cases.

Comment: True, I will edit to reflect original if. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you have too many conditions, you may benefit from factoring out the long condition into its own variable like so.

```
int main() 
{
    int var1 = 2;
    int var2 = 3;
    int var3 = 4;
    
    int condition 
        = (var1 == 2)
        && (var2 == 3)
        && (var3 == 4)
        ;
    
    if (condition) {
        /* do something */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For the first form there isn't, as you need to evaluate the three variables and check individually, but for the second:

> `if(var1 == 1 || var1 == 4 || var1 == 6)`

you have the possibility of using a `switch`, that has the advantage of requiring the evaluation of `var1` only once:

```
   switch (var1) {
   case 1: case 4: case 6:
       /* do whatever is the case */
       break;
   /* other cases here */
   }
```

most compilers will try to optimize that with a lookahead table, if possible.  Or, depending on the number of cases, you can have it yourself, with function pointers that can do the job:

```
typedef void (*paramless_cb)(void);

void do_on_146(void)
{
     /* whatever you want to do on 1, 4, and 6 */
}

void do_otherwise(void)
{
     /* whatever you want to do otherwise */
}

paramless_cb my_table[] = { 
     do_otherwise,   /* 0 */
     do_on_146,      /* 1 */
     do_otherwise,   /* 2 */
     do_otherwise,   /* 3 */
     do_on_146,      /* 4 */
     do_otherwise,   /* 5 */
     do_on_146,      /* 6 */
     do_otherwise,   /* 7 */
     do_otherwise,   /* 8 */
     do_otherwise,   /* 9 */
     do_otherwise,   /* 10 */
};
```

and then, in your code, just:

```
     my_table[val1]();
```

This is the by far fastest way, as it requires only a dereference (for the table entry) and the function call overhead, which both are independent of the number of entries and values, and the one selected by the compiler when you create a `switch` statement with a dense set of values (like the one avobe, which is complete)

The variadic solution for the first case, as annotated in the selected solution can be a way to write simpler (and more generic code) but not more efficient, as it involves a loop, an extra check to get out of the loop and a function call, but if you prefer more readable code:

```
#include <stdarg.h>
...
/* all parameters are references to variables, except the last, which
 * should be NULL */
int compare_all_to(int val, ...)
{
    va_list p;
    va_start(p, val);
    int *ref; 
    int result = 1;
    while (ref = va_arg(p, int *)) {
        if (val != *ref) {
            result = 0;
            break;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Then you will call it with something like:

```
    if (compare_all_to(1, &var1, &var2, &var3, NULL)) {
         /* something that is done only if var1 == 1 and var2 == 1 and var3 == 1 */
    }
```

but remember that the chain of tests in the original code will always be faster than that (as all the code is inlined, and no extra tests are made at all)

Comment: It's a totally different language, but in javascript you can do `switch (1) { case var1: {} case var2: {} }` for the first form, as a fun info tidbit

Comment: @Rogue, yes, and that's not possible to be made in C, as C requires the case labels to be statically known at compile time, which doesn't happen in Javascriptt.